# android - Using same fragment class in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that I want to use same `Fragment` in the each page with different variables. But when I do this, only one page of ViewPager is viewing and other pages are blank. How can i do this? I can't create different layout for each tab because I want to add them dynamically.

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

class FragmentStoreTabPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String[] pageTitles = {"Y","Z","X"};
    public FragmentStoreTabPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentStorePages.newInstance(pageTitles[position],position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Main Fragment that contains the ViewPager:

```
public class FragmentStore extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store,container,false);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_store);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStoreTabPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        TabPageIndicator tpi = (TabPageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator_store);
        tpi.setViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }

}
```

The Fragment that uses in ViewPager:

```
public class FragmentStorePages extends Fragment implements ReplaceListener {
    String categoryName;
    int categoryId;
    public static FragmentStorePages newInstance(String categoryName, int categoryId){
        FragmentStorePages fsp = new FragmentStorePages();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("categoryName", categoryName);
        args.putInt("categoryId", categoryId);
        fsp.setArguments(args);
        return fsp;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_pages,container,false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        categoryName = args.getString("categoryName");
        categoryId = args.getInt("categoryId");
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_store_pages,FragmentStoreSubCategories.newInstance(categoryName),"SubCategoryFragment").commit();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReplace(Bundle args) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use This `PagerAdapter`**

```
class FragmentStoreTabPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String[] pageTitles = {"Y","Z","X"};
    public FragmentStoreTabPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        FragmentStorePages fsp = new FragmentStorePages();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("categoryName", categoryName);
        args.putInt("categoryId", categoryId);
        fsp.setArguments(args);
        return fsp;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitles[position];
    }
}
```

**Use This `Fragment`**

```
public class FragmentStorePages extends Fragment implements ReplaceListener {
    String categoryName;
    int categoryId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_pages,container,false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if(args!=null && args.containsString("categoryName")&& args.containsString("categoryId")){
        categoryName = args.getString("categoryName");
        categoryId = args.getInt("categoryId");
        }           
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReplace(Bundle args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Use the above code and In onCreateView() remove getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_store_pages,FragmentStoreSubCategories.newInstance(categoryName),"SubCategoryFragment").commit();

Comment: Although you answer wasn't my exact answer, but you gave me an idea to solve the problem. I must use getChildFragmentManager(). Edit your answer and I will Accept it.

Comment: What is the need for getChildFragmentManager() here, There is no need for this one.http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: I edited your answer. I solved the problem by using getChildFragmentManager(). Accept edit and your answer will be accept ;)